# Ansible - Flat configuration files without subdirectories

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to use a configuration file with sections instead of entirely new directories?

ie: 
`/etc/ansible/roles/main.yml` would contain something like this:

```
[tasks]
-name: install ntp
 yum: pkg=ntp state=installed
 notify: restart-ntp

[handlers]
- name: restart-ntp
  service: name=ntp state=reloaded
```

Similarly for group_vars and host_vars, can I just put all my variables in one file instead of having to have a separate file for each group and host?

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* put all your variables in one file, but you will lose all of the hierarchy and scope that Ansible gives you with host, group, role, play and so on. Of course, you can try to *reproduce* that with a flat file, but... why ? Ansible already gives you this for free. Furthermore, it is likely that nobody else, including you in the future, will be able to understand your code, nevertheless reuse it.

So, while the answer is *technically* **yes**, I'm going to second @techraf and say that **no**, this is not possible.

Use the `ansible-galaxy init` generator to flesh out roles if you find that writing files is tedious. (see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/galaxy.html#create-roles)